# Mongojs: findOne() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongojs

I was trying to use findOne method. But it didn't show anything.It looks like it didn't execute. Would you like to help me solve this problem?

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var databaseUrl = "mongodb:local:27017/mydb";
var db = mongojs(databaseUrl, ["profiles"]);

var password;

db.profiles.findOne({"userId": "liu1234"}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of databaseUrl is incorrect. The mongodb driver is unable to find your database.

Try: 

`var databaseUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";`

The first part, `mongodb://`, refers to the protocol that mongodb uses to interact with the database. The next part, `localhost` , is a hostname that points to your machine. `:27017` refers to the default port that mongodb communicates over.  And, obviously, `/mydb` refers to your database.

If you're using a default configuration, you don't even need to specify the protocol, the host, or the port. Mongojs assumes the defaults if you don't enter them, so you can use this instead:

```js
var databaseUrl = "mydb";
```

For more information check out: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs